# Python dictionary update only if value is defined

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

If I run the following code:

```
import json

foo = [
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "occupation": "",
        "standing": "good",
        "locations": ["California"],
        "meta": { "last_updated": "2018-01-15" }
    },
    {
        "name": "",
        "occupation": "Carpenter",
        "standing": "bad",
        "locations": ["Arizona"],
        "meta": { "last_updated": "2018-01-15", "email": "bob@domain.com" }
    },
]

output = {}
for i in foo:
    output.update(i)
print json.dumps(output)
```

The final output is:

```
{
    "locations": [
        "Arizona"
    ],
    "meta": {
        "email": "bob@domain.com",
        "last_updated": "2018-01-15"
    },
    "name": "",
    "occupation": "Carpenter",
    "standing": "bad"
}
```

That's pretty good. However, I'm trying to figure out how I can pass a function to the update method that basically says, "Only update if the value is defined/not empty." Therefore, on the first iteration name is "Bob", and on the second iteration name remains Bob since name is essentially undefined.

The final output would look like this:

```
{
    "locations": [
        "Arizona"
    ],
    "meta": {
        "email": "bob@domain.com",
        "last_updated": "2018-01-15"
    },
    "name": "Bob",
    "occupation": "Carpenter",
    "standing": "bad"
}
```

Comment: This must be done either with a for-loop or a dict-comprehension where either a filtered version of the second dict (without empty values) or a completely new combined dictionary is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could filter the new dictionary you are updating on, with something like:

```
b = {'bla': '', 'b': 77, 'c': '9'}
new_b = { k: v for k,v in b.items() if v }
```

`new_b` will not have `bla` as an element anymore.

So, in your case:

```
for i in foo:
    output.update({ k: v for k,v in i.items() if v })
```

Comment: True, for recursion you would have to go deeper "by hand", or build a quick dictionary filterer function that is recursive, and use that before updating...

Answer (score 1):

you could take advantage of the inherent boolean values of all data-types, by checking to see if the key is present and/or not an empty/default value:

```
output = {}
for i in foo:
    for k, v in i.iteritems():
        if not output.get(k):
            output[k] = v

In [6]: output
Out[6]:
{'locations': ['California'],
 'meta': {'last_updated': '2018-01-15'},
 'name': 'Bob',
 'occupation': 'Carpenter',
 'standing': 'good'}
```

Note though that one disadvantage this has is that if a key DOES exist, BUT is mapped to a data-type's default (boolean false) value, it will be overridden:

```
In [7]: output = {"foo": 0}

In [8]: if not output.get("foo"):
   ...:     output['foo'] = 1
   ...:

In [9]: output
Out[9]: {'foo': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to pair all values with the same key. First, the code calls `dict.items` on every dictionary in `foo` and flattens the result, thus enabling the groups to be found:

```
import itertools
foo = [
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "occupation": "",
    "standing": "good",
    "locations": ["California"],
    "meta": { "last_updated": "2018-01-15" }
},
{
    "name": "",
    "occupation": "Carpenter",
    "standing": "bad",
    "locations": ["Arizona"],
    "meta": { "last_updated": "2018-01-15", "email": "bob@domain.com" }
  },
]
new_data = [(a, map(lambda x:x[-1], list(b))) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(itertools.chain(*map(lambda x:x.items(), foo)), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_data = {a:filter(None, b)[-1] for a, b in new_data}
```

Output:

```
{'occupation': 'Carpenter', 'standing': 'bad', 'meta': {'last_updated': '2018-01-15', 'email': 'bob@domain.com'}, 'locations': ['Arizona'], 'name': 'Bob'}
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 can you clarify?

Comment: I wanted to say that this looks very complicated and very hard to understand.